# Facebook graph API : audio share

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Can I share audio using facebook graphic API

- Can I directly upload audio on facebook server like video?
- Can I share audio link on facebook and it will show embedded player on facebook?

I have tried this solution [ios Facebook Graph API - post Audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301118/ios-facebook-graph-api-post-audio-file) , but it doesn't work as expected

What I tried is to share audio link http://bit.ly/Ok4ZX6 but show it on facebook like a normal link not with embedded player https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld67c.png

**Edit**

*Code I have use :*

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
[params setObject:text forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:title forKey:@"name"];
[params setObject:fileUrl forKey:@"source"];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

*Also used this code too :*

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
NSString *attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{'media': [{'type': 'mp3', 'src': '%@', 'title': '%@'}], 'messgae': 'Messgae Messgae Messgae', 'name': 'Name Name Name', 'href': '%@'}",amazon_link, title, link];
[params setObject:attachment forKey:@"attachment"];
[params setObject:text forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:@"stream.publish" forKey:@"method"];
[facebook requestWithParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Hey Amit you wrote that you are able to share video in facebook ... can you tell me how are you doing this?

Answer (score 2):

What solution from that link did you try? Post your own code. I also noticed that your audio link doesn't work, atleast not for me.

I think the correct way is to use the "source" field in the graph api, not "link".

This is a good page on the developer reference:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

---

To upload a video using the graph API you can do this. You also need to be authorized to the publish_stream permission.

```
NSString * file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mov"];
NSData * video = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
         @"title", @"title",
         @"description", @"description",
         video, @"video.mov",
         @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
     nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                     andParams:dict
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I have add the code in question.. yes that link is not working. even I try other working link but same result.

Comment: I want either **Can directly upload audio on facebook server like video.** *OR* **can share audio link and it will show embedded player on facebook.**

Comment: I am able to upload the video on facebook.. my question here is regards Audio post

Answer (score 0):

Soundcloud use og:video tags to show the embedded player. The video tags accept SWF files, so it's possible to load up an interactive audio player widget. Try using the [OG Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://soundcloud.com/elliegoulding/hanging-on-ft-tinie-tempah) to see the tags.

Currently, this seems like the only strategy to show a player when content is shared.

Comment: Although, it looks like they're working on a much better solution: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. Its working for me..

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//Posting audio file
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dookudu" ofType:@"mp3"];
FbGraphFile *file=[[FbGraphFile alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
[variables setObject:file forKey:@"file"];

FbGraphResponse *response=[fbgraph doGraphPost:@"me/videos" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"response %@",response.htmlResponse);
```